Why does the RIG not move with the rest of the leg?
Why does the RIG not move with the rest of the leg?




i send here gifs link for show better..


https://jmp.sh/s/OiOmADgNAYmCqHGVAHkj
https://jmp.sh/s/wvQ193LgrmPGkXb0ut98

Hello it's hard to understand, what do you show with the arrows? Also maybe share your file?

i send gif to here for is be clear

it looks like the bone doesn't follow their controller, also the controller should not deform the mesh, could you please share your file so that we check the rigging?

Looks like you might be using Rigify, and that might be the metarig? Not entirely sure but the metarig is just the basis to generate the actual rig you parent the mesh to. It won't actually be used in animation. The Armature with the multicolored bones and widgets is the actual rig to parent to, the silver armature with the default bones is the metarig.
